# Changing a neural network to not overfit

Tags: neural-network, classification, scikit-learn

I am trying to classify around 400K data with 13 attributes. I have used python sklearn's SVM package, but it didn't work, and then I learned that SVM's are not suitable for large dataset classification. Then I used the (sklearn) ANN using the following MLPClassifier:

```
MLPClassifier(solver='adam', alpha=1e-5, random_state=1,activation='relu', max_iter=500)
```

and trained the system using 200K samples, and tested the model on the remaining ones. The classification worked well. However, my concern is that the system is over trained or overfit. Can you please guide me on the number of hidden layers and node sizes to make sure that there is no overfit? (I have learned that the default implementation has 100 hidden neurons. Is it ok to use the default implementation as is?)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid overfit,

While model building with [MLPClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html),

1. Use `early_stopping = True`. This stops the training when there is
   no improvement with validation data.
2. Using default node size is fine for most of the cases, until it is
   has large number of features.
3. Since you have more data, you split with train, test and validation
   and validate the scores.
4. Check with various metrics (f1_score, precision, recall etc.). This
   is highly useful when it comes with imbalanced data set.
5. If you are highly concerned about over-fitting, you can explore [cross_val_predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html). The error standard deviation shows, how well the model will work on unseen data.

You will get more things, related to the data you have.

Comment: thanks @vivek-ananthan!

Comment: I haven't used validation data before, but will check it. However, early_stopping = True also uses a part of training test as validation data. In that case what will be the purpose of second validation test? I will also check  cross_val_predict as well. Thanks again!

Comment: With second validation set, we can confirm how well the model is generalized (after trained with earlystopping). This shows the stability of the model. This is just an extra degree, not mandatory. We can follow this if we have more number of data. 

Please upvote answer if hels. Thanks.